# Download file from SharePoint Online (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint

I need to make a .bat file to be able to download a .zip file that is hosted on a sharepoint online, this is the code.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

rem FOR DOWNLOADING FILES, THIS SCRIPT IS USING THE "BITSADMIN.EXE" SYSTEM FILE.
rem IT IS PRESENT ON MOST WINDOWS VERSION, PROBABLY FROM WINDOWS XP TO WINDOWS 10.


:SETUP

rem URL (TEST FILE):
SET "FILE_URL=https://testname.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/sites/siteexample/folderexample/filetest.zip?csf=1&web=1&e=1Pt6Hx"

rem SAVE IN CUSTOM LOCATION:
rem SET "SAVING_TO=C:\Test\filetest.zip"

rem SAVE IN THE CURRENT DIRECTORY
SET "SAVING_TO=filetest.zip"
SET "SAVING_TO=%~dp0%SAVING_TO%"

:MAIN

ECHO.
ECHO DOWNLOAD SCRIPT EXAMPLE
ECHO.
ECHO FILE URL: "%FILE_URL%"
ECHO SAVING TO:  "%SAVING_TO%"
ECHO.

PAUSE

rem UNCOMENT AND MODIFY THE NEXT LINE IF YOU NEED TO USE A PROXY SERVER:
rem CALL :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON "PROXY-SERVER.COM:8080"
 
rem THE MAIN DOWNLOAD COMMAND:
CALL :DOWNLOAD_FILE "%FILE_URL%" "%SAVING_TO%"

rem UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE FOR DISABLING THE PROXY (IF YOU USED IT):
rem CALL :DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF

:RESULT
ECHO.
IF EXIST "%SAVING_TO%" ECHO YOUR FILE HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED.
IF NOT EXIST "%SAVING_TO%" ECHO ERROR, YOUR FILE COULDN'T BE DOWNLOADED.
ECHO.

:EXIT_SCRIPT
PAUSE
EXIT /B




rem FUNCTIONS SECTION


:DOWNLOAD_FILE
    rem BITSADMIN COMMAND FOR DOWNLOADING FILES:
    bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority FOREGROUND %1 %2
GOTO :EOF

:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_ON
    rem FUNCTION FOR USING A PROXY SERVER:
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob OVERRIDE %1
GOTO :EOF

:DOWNLOAD_PROXY_OFF
    rem FUNCTION FOR STOP USING A PROXY SERVER:
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings mydownloadjob NO_PROXY
GOTO :EOF
```

The detail is that it **shows me two errors and it does not allow me to download, the error is 0x00000005 and 0x8019019**3, but the error itself does not say much.
Any idea to be able to solve this error?

From now on, thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Are you running your script elevated? or are you running it as a particular user? Does that user have appropriate permissions? It would help if you were to provide us at least that information.

Comment: @Compo, thank you for your answer. I already tried to run it with administrator permissions and with the same results. For the user, it is a corporate account, for which in theory it is supposed to automatically log in to the SP.

Comment: I should also mention that bitsadmin was deprecated way back in Windows 7/Server 2008 R2, _(which is good, as it was prone to errors)_. You should really be using the [PowerShell BITS cmdlets](https://ss64.com/ps/bits.html) nowadays.